CSP 'unsafe-inline' client side rendering issue
I am working on a project created using create-react-app and Material-UI for styles and Nginix is redirecting the request to my app. But now I have implemented the CSP header by which all the inline style tag which as MUI behind the scene use 'css-in-js' way are getting purged out due to which my application UIi is getting distorted.
I have looked for outside resource and find out there are 2 possible way to solve this:

hash (sha256-..) which is generated unique for each <style>....<style/> tag so just copy paste it in SCP header config.

Create a unique nonce for every request and insert it in <style> tag.


So is there any way to mitigate this problem?
But on 1st approach there are around 200+ components using MUI so it means 1000+ hashes to be generated which is nightmare to add in CSP header config. Add for nonce MUI say to use SSR approach but my application is CSR based.
This is my CSP header what looks like in index.html of react app:
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src 'self' http://frontend-eoffice-test.apps.ocp4.pacosta.com;
    style-src 'self' https://fonts.googleapis.com;
    font-src 'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com data:;
    script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' blob:;
    connect-src 'self';
    worker-src 'self';
    img-src 'self' data: blob:;
    frame-ancestors 'self' http://frontend-eoffice-test.apps.ocp4.pacosta.com;
    form-action 'self' http://frontend-eoffice-test.apps.ocp4.pacosta.com;"
/> 

